# Two separate portfolio pages

Tags: categories

Is it possible to have two different portfolio pages with different items in each one?

I use a free theme called [ADAPT](http://wpexplorer.me/adapt/), and I have two "portfolio template" pages, NEW vehicles and USED vehicles. An excavator or a tractor may be NEW or USED and have the same category (excavator or tractor). I'm having an issue where USED equipment is showing up in the NEW page.

What method should I use to restrict only specific categories to specific pages?

Comment: Please show the exact setup + code you're currently using.